# jQuery setTimeout - not working when using to update data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of thumbnails. When I click on a thumbnail, I want the image to load after half a second.  Here's my code:

```
$('ul#thumbs li img').click(function() {

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('img#image').attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("_thumb", ""));
    }, 500);

});
```

When I click on one of the thumbs, nothing happens. If I remove the setTimeout function, and just have the image load immediately, it works fine.

Anybody know why the event wouldn't fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` isn't what you think it is.  When you use `setTimeout`, `this` is no longer a reference to the current element when the function gets executed.

You'll need to make sure you are keeping track of the proper element, like so:

```
$('ul#thumbs li img').click(function() {
    var thumbImg = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('img#image').attr("src", $(thumbImg).attr("src").replace("_thumb", ""));
    }, 500);

});
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scope of `this` in the timeout function try this:

```
$('ul#thumbs li img').click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('img#image').attr("src", self.attr("src").replace("_thumb", ""));
    }, 500);

});
```

Or even better this:

```
$('ul#thumbs li img').click(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("_thumb", "");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('img#image').attr("src", src);
    }, 500);

});
```

Comment: note: the 2nd example might not work if the `src` attribute could change within the timeout period.  if it is static, it will work fine though.